# how to send FFT array consist of 512 Samples Data From arduino to raspberry pi using i2c and this is the code for FFT any Suggestion plz?

Tags: arduino-uno, i2c

```
#include "arduinoFFT.h"
float y, x = 0;
#define t PE_0
#define SAMPLES 1024             //Must be a power of 2
#define SAMPLING_FREQUENCY 1024 //Hz, must be less than 10000 due to ADC
arduinoFFT FFT = arduinoFFT();


unsigned int sampling_period_us;
unsigned long microseconds;

double  vReal[SAMPLES];
double vImag[SAMPLES];

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);

  sampling_period_us = round(1000000 * (1.0 / SAMPLING_FREQUENCY));
}

void loop() {

  /*SAMPLING*/
  for (int i = 0; i < SAMPLES; i++)
  {
    microseconds = micros();    //Overflows after around 70 minutes!
    y=(analogRead(t))*(3.3/4095.0)-1.65;
    x=((1000.0*y)/201.0);
    vReal[i] = x;
    vImag[i] = 0;

    while (micros() < (microseconds + sampling_period_us)) {
    }
  }

  /*FFT*/
  FFT.Windowing(vReal, SAMPLES, FFT_WIN_TYP_HANN , FFT_FORWARD);
  FFT.Compute(vReal, vImag, SAMPLES, FFT_FORWARD);
  FFT.ComplexToMagnitude(vReal, vImag, SAMPLES);
  double peak = FFT.MajorPeak(vReal, SAMPLES, SAMPLING_FREQUENCY);

  /*PRINT RESULTS*/
  //Serial.println(peak);     //Print out what frequency is the most dominant.

  for (int i = 0; i < (SAMPLES / 2); i++)
  {
    /*View all these three lines in serial terminal to see which frequencies has which amplitudes*/

    //Serial.println((i * 1.0 * SAMPLING_FREQUENCY) / SAMPLES, 1);
    //Serial.print(" ");
    Serial.println(vReal[i], 1);    //View only this line in serial plotter to visualize the bins
  }

  delay(1000);  //Repeat the process every second OR:
  //while (1);      //Run code once
Serial.println("//");
}
```

Comment: this is the line that you have to replace with I2C comm `Serial.println(vReal[i], 1);`  .......... you have to start by writing code that sends just one *Double* between the two devices .... then merge the two codes

Comment: Are you thinking of using the Arduino as the master or the Pi as the master?